# Using a regular expression in a Greasemonkey @include?

Tags: regex, greasemonkey

I want to specify a bit better where my Greasemonkey script runs.

```
// @include     https://example.com/*
```

Works fine, but it is too inaccurate, I want something like:

```
// @include     https://example.com/xx-xx/Asset/*
```

xx could be any letter a-z, - is just dash, xx could be any letter a-z. My Idea was use regular expression for any 5 symbols, but I don't know how to properly use it. This is not working and lot more expression which I have tried to:

```
// @include     https://example.com/...../Asset/*
```

Any idea how handle this?

**Update:**
This sort of works:

```
// @include     https://example.com/*/Asset/*
```

Comment: An asterisk in regex does *not* match any character, it means the preceding atom can appear any number of times, including zero. If the first example works, then it's probably a wildcard or glob syntax, not regex.

Comment: @BrockAdams I don't doubt it. I just meant that it didn't look like regex, which you've confirmed it isn't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [*Include and exclude rules* in the Greasemonkey documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules).
`*` is a special wildcard, NOT per the usual javascript rules.
To use full-powered regular expressions, **Greasemonkey provides [a special syntax for `@include`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules#Regular_Expressions).**

So your `https://example.com/xx-xx/Asset/*` pattern would become:

```
// @include  /^https:\/\/example\.com\/[a-z]{2}\-[a-z]{2}\/Asset\/.*$/
```

You can [see an explanation of that regex at RegExr.com](http://www.regexr.com/38sk0).