# How to match any top level domain in Tempermonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have the following script to automatically follow the IFRAME in Google's image search result:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Follow IFRAME in Google image search
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://images.google.de/imgres?*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

location.replace(document.querySelector('iframe').src)
```

It works fine.

Now I want to make it independent of the German top level domain. But when I change the match to

```
// @match        http://images.google.*/imgres?*
```

it stops working. Chrome's [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) of the `@match` option says:

```
┌──────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Bad pattern          │ Why it's bad                                          │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ http://foo.*.bar/baz │ If '*' is in the host, it must be the first character │
└──────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

How to match any top level domain with such a restriction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression in a Greasemonkey @include?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783774/using-a-regular-expression-in-a-greasemonkey-include)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I have tagged the question with [tag:greasemonkey], because this kind of script is inspired by Greasemonkey. But my question asks about [tag:tampermonkey], which is a different implementation. And I am asking about the `@match` option and not an `@include` option.

Comment: The solution is to use a regex, which you can use by using `@include` instead of `@match`. AFAIK, [Tampermonkey supports `@include`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_include).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara From the documentation you have linked, I would say, that `@include` does not support any regular expression as an argument.

Comment: Oh wow, that's lame, I thought it did. In that case, CV retracted.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara But your suggestion works although it is no regular expression. It allows globing at the end of the domain, which is not allowed by `@match`. Thanks!

Comment: `@include` does support RegEx in both Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey, I've used this directive for exactly that reason for years. BUT it is deprecated (as being part of manifest v2) and, at least for extension manifests directly, will be completely unsupported in "January 2023" (June for enterprise exceptions) https://www.vshsolutions.com/blogs/chrome-extension-manifest-v3-a-migration-guide/
If TM/GM are using Manifest v2 to handle the parsing, our days are numbered :(

Answer (score 2):

> TLDR: Use `@include` with the magic wildcard `.tld`

In [Tampermonkey](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/1864) and in [Greasemonkey](http://underpop.online.fr/u/userscripts/help/how-to-master-the-include-and-exclude-directives-with-user-scripts.htm) the `@include` directive allows you to use `.tld` as a magical wildcard.

```js
// WORKS IN TAMPERMONKEY AND GREASEMONKEY, PROBABLY VIOLENTMONKEY TOO
//
// @include      https://images.google.tld/*
```

Where `.tld` will match any of the standardised top-level domains.

Note that this **will not work** with `@match` and it might not work in all userscripting extensions.

```js
// DOES NOT WORK
//
// @match        https://images.google.tld/*
```

Curiously, it is not in TamperMonkey's [documentation](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#meta:include) (October 2023).  Perhaps because it is not widely compatible, but very tempting to use.

Furthermore, ESLint will complain if you use `@include`.  I just ignore it.

---

I think the userscripting community should embrace the `.tld` solution, because these don't work for me:

```js
// DO NOT WORK
//
// @match        https://images.google.tld/*
// @match        https://images.google.*.*/*
```

And whilst these do work, they are clearly horrible:

```js
// WORKS, BUT HORRIBLE and possibly deprecated
//
// @include      /https:\/\/images\.google\.[a-z]{2,3}(\.[a-z]{2})?\/.*/

// OR

// WIDELY COMPATIBLE, BUT HORRIBLE
//
// @match        https://images.google.com/*
// @match        https://images.google.de/*
// @match        https://images.google.fr/*
// @match        https://images.google.co.uk/*
// @match        https://images.google.com.my/*
// ... and 67 more lines ...
```